# Microservice download queue

Tags: queue, message-queue

I am making a **website**, where I provide a button which can :

- `POST` a `JSON` to a route (nothing hard for now)
- but the process should also start multiples `system commands`, and at the end of it provide a zip the user can download

To do that, I think I need a `queue`. Because two users connected on the same time CANNOT start the process. 
Is a queue ok ? But I do not know how to retain the session and send back the zip file...

PS: I am using `angular2` & a `Python WS`.

Comment: Why two users connected at the same time cannot start the process? That is bad design. A lot of system commands is bad design as well. Give more details as to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

There are three parts to your question:

**First, allow only one execution of your system commands per user at a time.**

This could be as simple as maintaining a synchronized flag bit per user, which stores 1 if the request can be processed, 0 otherwise. Whenever a post request comes, first check if this flag is set or not. Continue if it is not 1 return some non-200 status code. Else, set it to 0 and trigger the commands.

**Second, handle multiple POST requests that trigger the system commands.**

You should use a queue only if your system commands take more time and usually run in the background.

**Three, how to retain the session**

Retaining a session is not a good idea. You have two options. One, client continuously pools to another end point to check if the zip creation is complete or not. Second, (better than first) use websockets to send the notification back to client once the zip creation is complete.